# What is the actual distribution that we are modelling in case of a Bayesian Regression Model?

Tags: regression, bayesian, neural-networks, inference, bayesian-optimization

I have come across blog posts that speak about modelling a regression problem using Bayesian approaches. I completely understand that, to set up example data, they generate a sine wave using a one dimensional data $X$ and then add Gaussian noise around the $Y_i$ value for every $X_i$ and consider this as a training data.

Now, when we say we are going to determine the parameters of a probability distribution which generated our data, which data are we referring to? Are we modelling the parameters of the distribution that generated $X$ or are we talking of generating $Y$?

Comment: Links are useful. There are lots of useless "blogs" out there from people trying to make names for themselves. Regression is always about modeling the conditional $Y$, that is we get $X$ for free. In Bayesian, we don't even bother with a prior on $X$. In Machine Learning, we call it a "supervised learning" process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bayesian inference we typically are interested in the conditional distribution of our parameters $\theta$ given data. In the case of regression, we condition on our predictors $X$ and outcomes $y$.

Given known Gaussian noise with known variance, this reduces to inferring the conditional distribution of regression coefficients $\beta$ given the data $X,y$:

$$
p(\beta|X,y) \propto p(y|\beta,X) p(\beta)
$$

Since in linear regression $y \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2)$, $p(y|\beta, X)$ is the likelihood of a normal distribution. $p(\beta)$ is the prior for regression coefficients, often inverse gamma.

Thus we are interested in the probability distribution over the parameters that generated $y$ given $X$.

Comment: Not sure what a linear prior for $\beta$ is, but hopefully nobody noticed that!

Comment: Your last statement "Thus we are ..." kind of summarized the whole thing beautifully - thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, I'm relatively new to Bayes so it's helpful for me to try to explain things clearly. Cheers

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question: what we are *modeling* is the distribution of $y$ conditional on $X$ and $\beta.$ Indeed, in almost any good Bayesian analysis we care so little about the *prior* distribution of $\beta$ that we freely and dramatically change that distribution to verify that our results are robust to the prior distribution; without that, it is hard to support claims that the results have any objectivity.  The *posterior* distribution of $\beta$ is in most cases just a *nuisance* because it quantifies our uncertainty about the conditional distribution of $y$ on $X.$

Comment: It's likely my fault, but I don't understand how I failed to answer the question. My reading of your comment implies that we are interested in the conditional of $y$ given $X, \beta$, while my post implies that the conditional of $\beta$ given $X,y$ was the distribution of interest. That seems a philosophical disagreement (seemingly fairly common in Bayesian stats) rather than a difference in content.